# Android - How to implement getListItemClick() in this case?

Tags: android, android-layout, listactivity

When I click on an item from the list, I want a TextView inside it to change visibility from "gone" to "visible" and display the item position that was clicked. This should be done without the glitches that result from [incorrectly manipulating the TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022034/android-onlistitemclick-appears-to-be-acting-upon-more-than-one-list-item). How should I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022192/1267661) I'll assume that you want each TextView to display different data, so let's add a new member to your adapter and appropriate getters and setters to your Adapter:

```
private SparseArray<String> secondary = new SparseArray<String>();

public String getSecondary(int position) {
    return secondary.get(position, "");
}
public void setSecondary(int position, String value) {
    secondary.put(position, value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();  // Updates the ViewGroup automatically!
}
```

SpareArrays are better at sets without a predictable index, but you can use a List, HashMap, etc if you want something different.  Now tweak `onListItemClick()` to use the new methods:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String clickedPosition = "Clicked position = " + position;
    mAdapter.setSecondary(position, clickedPosition);
}
```

Lastly update `getView()` to show `textClickedPosition` only when `secondary` has data:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPosition);
textView.setText(event);

textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textClickedPosition);
String string = getSecondary(position);
if(!string.isEmpty()) {
    textView.setText(string);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else // You must hide the view otherwise you will see odd behavior for the recycle method
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

return view;
```

On a final note, you *really* should watch the Google I/O lectures like [Turbo Charge your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) they contain a wealth of knowledge!

Comment: Thanks! The else part is what I was missing :) and I have watched the first part of the lecture (my implementation even has a ViewHolder now), I'll be sure to watch the rest as soon as possible!